# New line in the gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage in which I let user to enter the contents, even if they change the line frequently in the textbox, the gridview when retrieves it from the database doesn't show any new line.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this in your RowDataBound event if you're using C#

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

where `e.Row.Cells[0].Text` is the text retrieved from the database.